# How to return custom information in an ExceptionFilterAttribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

The project lead wants me to create a custom exception filter for our Web API to catch all unhandled exceptions.  I've added a custom filter in our WebApiConfig file, and it's working, but it doesn't give all the detail he wants.  He wants to return a 500 error with this information in the body:

```
{
  "code": 500,
  "message": "My custom message"
}
```

My handler code shown below returns a 500 error, but the body only shows

```
{
  "message": "My custom message"
}
```

How can I customize this to add the "code" number, even though that information is redundant?

```cs
public class UnhandledExceptionAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        string message = "My custom message";
        context.Response = context.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`CreateResponse<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.createresponse(v=vs.118).aspx) extension method:

```
public class UnhandledExceptionAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        string message = "My custom message";
        context.Response = context.Request.CreateResponse(
            HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
            new {
                code = 500,
                message = message
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Federico, that works perfectly.  I knew there had to be an easy answer, but I wasn't finding it.  Thanks.